# Add tags to custom post type without menu link

Tags: custom-post-types, taxonomy

I've worked out how to add tags to custom post types using

`'taxonomies' => array('post_tag')`

However this adds another "Tags" submenu under my custom post type menu which I do not want. How do I remove this submenu?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove the submenu *Tags* link from the admin menu, you might try

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'custom_admin_menu' );
function custom_admin_menu() {
        // debug to find the correct submenu slug:
        // global $submenu;
        // print_r($submenu);

        $menu_slug = 'edit.php?post_type=infographics';
        $submenu_slug = 'edit-tags.php?taxonomy=post_tag&amp;post_type=infographics';

        remove_submenu_page( $menu_slug, $submenu_slug );
}
```

if your custom post type is *infograhpics*.

By viewing the global `$submenu` array you can find the correct menu slugs.